# Javascript - How to make get request to local json file?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, get, axios

I looked through posts and people seem to do it as I did, however, I get a 404.

my json file:

```
{
    "posts": [          
      {
        "title": "titlee",
        "image": "./public/...",
        "submitDate": "12-09-2017",
        "username": "name name"
      },

    ]
}
```

My folder structure is:

```
my-app/data/links.json

my-app/src/App.js
```

In App.js use axios so:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000//data/links.json')
```

I also tried:

```
axios.get('../data/links.json')
```

Thanks!!

EDIT: Its a react App and the double slash was a mistake but its also not working without double slash.

UPDATE: I used react create app and apparently when you put the json file into the public folder, it does work! I guess its because of how webpack is set up or something like that.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000//data/links.json` you have double slash

Comment: ah yes sorry, but without the double slash its also not working

Comment: its a react app so i dont have that but my index.js is inside src as App.js where I make the call

Answer (score 0):

For such purposes i can recommand [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). If you follow the docs you can expose your json on any port you like with a single CLI command, so in your case

```
json-server --watch my-app/data/links.json
```

Hopefully it will help you ;-)